# Cron job not exiting in Catalina; leaving zombie processes

Tags: bash, catalina

I just upgraded to catalina a few days ago. I'm still using bash which has been installed with homebrew.

The `ps aux | grep bash` command is showing a new bash process is forked every minute. After a few hours I'll have hundreds of bash processes running in the background. Each of these is accompanied by a cron process.

The cron job in `crontab -e` is:

`* * * * * /Users/me/bin/sync_task`

This task runs a bash script for syncing my taskwarrior projects:

```
#!/bin/bash
TASKRC=$HOME/.taskrc_uc_team
/usr/local/bin/task synchronize
unset TASKRC
/usr/local/bin/task synchronize
```

Does anyone know why the bash and cron processes might not be exiting?

Comment: Looks like an old cron job set to run every minute was the culprit.

Comment: Possibly related, there appears to be a bug handling stderr output from cron jobs on Catalina; see: [“cron” processes piling up](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372522/cron-processes-piling-up).

Comment: Also, remember `cron` has been deprecated for `launchd`.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/373643/66939) anser solved this problem for me (redirecting stdout/stderr to /dev/null).